# HELP Please! Depth of member

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

What is meant by "depth of member" and what is the formula of it?
Can I use it in moment of inertia formula?

---

[image]

How to use the given information to answer the question?
and Thank you.

Comment: more context required, but either the depth is measured or it may be calculated to meet some criteria.

Comment: Shame the edit removed the explanation ....

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read your writing and I will add more details for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The depth of a member is merely equal to its total height (or whichever total dimension is parallel to the loading direction).